# Is it a good idea to do double AES encryption with 2 different keys, when one is held by the user and one stored on the server?

Tags: encryption, aes

I'm building a web app. The app needs to keep certain data within the database very secure.

Please assume for the moment that I don't have a HSM or Key-Management facility and can't afford to implement one.

When storing away a user's data, I want to generate a random key and provide it to the user. This will not be stored anywhere on my server. This key will be used to encrypt the data.

I don't feel comfortable with the user having the only key required to decode the ciphertext, as I don't know how they're going to store it, whether they're going to email it around, etc.

As such, I intended to apply some further form of encryption on the server-side.

So first, I would encrypt the data using the random key provided to the user, and then encrypt that again, using either a static key, or a second random key which I WILL store on the server/db.

By not storing the random key provided to the user, the data remains protected if the server is compromised, as there is nowhere within the server or associated components that a hacker can obtain all the keys required to decrypt the data. They may get access to the static key, or second random key, but this won't be enough.

I was thinking of using AES for both the first and second encryption.

- Is this a bad idea?
- Should I instead create an encryption key that is a formula of the user's random key and the server-stored key, and then only encrypt once?
- Should I do something completely different?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does using the same encryption algorithm multiple times make a difference?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/58781/does-using-the-same-encryption-algorithm-multiple-times-make-a-difference)

Answer (score 2):

If the server is going to decrypt the data when presented with the user's key, that second layer of encryption does not protect against a leaked user's key.  Whoever has that key can decrypt the data.

A second layer of encryption *does* make a brute force attack harder, but if the key for the second layer is stored with the data that advantage vanishes as well.

Finally, your biggest worry isn't the user leaking the key, it is the user losing access to the key.  "I've got a new computer; please send my secret key again."

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not all that concerned with the user losing the key. It will just mean they will need to re-do a fairly simple task.

I see your points though. It seems the 2nd key adds nothing in my scenario. I still think it wouldn't hurt to contribute to the key from the server side, although probably by making the encryption key a function of the user string and a server side string, rather than encrypting twice.

Comment: If I store the key for a 2nd layer of encryption on another server, that will improve security, would it not? It wouldn't have to be a key management server or HSM necessarily, but the fact that its on another server would still be advantageous. Let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The second key has to be available to the server with the encrypted data.  If it *is* available, it doesn't improve security in the case of a server compromise.

Comment: If a hacker enters my server, I would hope that I could find this out in a short enough timeframe such that they aren't in there for too long. If they take full control of the server, to the point where I can't access it myself right away, at least I can shutdown or change passwords on the other server holding the key.

Also, if they just download the database and files and take it with them for later analysis and attempted decryption, they'll find that the key is nowhere within those files. By this time I will have hopefully done enough to ensure they can't return.

Hence more secure, yes?

Comment: Nope.  You are talking about security by obscurity.  If something is accessible to an adversary, you have to assume that the adversary will get it during a compromise.  Read about Kerckhoffs's Principle, restated slightly as Shannon's Maxim. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle

Comment: In reading your link and some other links on the topic it still sounds to me like it is better to add security by obscurity than to not. Of course, this shouldn't be your only measure or your main measure. I'm not really "relying" on it, I'm just adding it to make it slightly more difficult. You can't really argue that the scenarios I raised above aren't possible?

Comment: From Wikipedia:

A system may use security through obscurity as a defense in depth measure....An attacker's first step is usually information gathering; this step is delayed by security through obscurity. The technique stands in contrast with security by design and open security, although many real-world projects include elements of all strategies

Comment: Well, it's your stuff, but here is Shannon's Maxim: "one ought to design systems under the assumption that the enemy will immediately gain full familiarity with them."